# Piping difference of grep -c's with different regex to bc

Tags: grep, regular-expression, pipe, bc

I need to find the number of words in a file (1 word per line) that do not contain some set of letters. To do this I want to take the difference of `grep -c '.' <file>` and `grep -c '<other_pattern>' <file>`.  I tried piping to bc with the following command `echo "(grep -c '.' <file>) - (grep -c '<other_pattern>' <file>)" | bc`.  The result simply said syntax error.  I was hoping someone had insight as what syntax is necessary for bc to accept the results of the grep calls.  I need to do this in a single command as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your system's `grep` not have the facility (`-v`, `--invert-match`) to invert the match?

Comment: Yes, actually. I realized just before seeing this. I had originally tried negating within the pattern and some other post on regex negating made me shy away from it. But using inverting matching solved my problem.

Comment: also - if you have a strict requirement for doing this in a single command, steeldriver's got it. (mine uses a built-in echo, two greps, and a bc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply missing two dollar signs to enable command substitution:

```
echo $(grep -c '.' <file>) - $(grep -c '<other_pattern>' <file>) | bc
```

I also removed the quotes, since they aren't really necessary.

Comment: looks like I answered the problem that you asked, but steeldriver answered the question that you _really_ had.  (`grep -cv`)

Comment: Ahh, thank you.  I did ultimately get what I wanted with inverted matching but this is very useful as well